# Controlling PTC WindChill with VBA

Tags: javascript, java, vba, excel

Follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376137/controlling-windchill-using-vba)

Managed to put in the data and click some buttons. For the last part I need to click a tab in the [following screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuYR4.jpg). Trying to press the Related Objects tab with the following HTML. The href just states an # and I have no idea to trigger this.. any tips? When I press the tab manually and inspect the element a new html file is visible with the data...

Thanks!

```
    <DIV class="x-tab-panel-header x-tab-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable x-tab-panel-header-plain" id=ext-gen1118 style="WIDTH: 1865px; MozUserSelect: none; KhtmlUserSelect: none" unselectable="on"><DIV class=x-tab-strip-wrap id=ext-gen1121 style="WIDTH: 1865px">
    <UL class="x-tab-strip x-tab-strip-top" id=ext-gen1123>
        <LI class=" x-tab-strip-active" id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_object_infoDetails_cadx _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1126></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1127 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Details</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_msr_modelStructureGWT _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1128></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1129 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Structure</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_object_content_cadx _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1130></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1131 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Content</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_object_related_cadx _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1132></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1133 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Related Objects</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_object_changesTab _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1134></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1135 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Changes</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_object_history_cadx _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1136></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1137 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">History</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_object_requirementTraceabilityTab _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1138></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1139 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Traceability</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_sysnav_sysnavTab _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1140></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1141 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Relationship Explorer</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI id=infoPageinfoPanelID__infoPage_myTab_tab_jcaGen_1996253653 _nodup="30865"><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1142></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1143 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text ">Family Table</SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI class=" x-tab-with-icon privateEditableTab" id=infoPageinfoPanelID__new_tab_action><A class=x-tab-strip-close id=ext-gen1344></A><A class=x-tab-right id=ext-gen1345 href="#"><EM class=x-tab-left><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-inner><SPAN class="x-tab-strip-text tab-add" qtip="New Tab "></SPAN></SPAN></EM></A></LI>
            <LI class=x-tab-edge id=ext-gen1124 _nodup="30865"><SPAN class=x-tab-strip-text>&nbsp;</SPAN></LI>
        <DIV class=x-clear id=ext-gen1125></DIV>
    <DIV class=x-dock-tab-drop-highlight id=ext-gen1145 style="VISIBILITY: hidden"><IMG id=ext-gen1146 style="POSITION: absolute" src="netmarkets/javascript/ext/dockPanel/pos.gif"></DIV></UL></DIV>
<DIV class=x-tab-strip-spacer id=ext-gen1122></DIV></DIV>
```

Comment: to control wind chill programmatically you will need a [HAARP machine](https://geopolitics.co/2015/06/06/us-air-force-admits-they-can-control-weather/). to provide a more descriptive title you will need to hit the "edit" button.

Comment: As you wish sir :P Funny machine but doesn't help my case I think..

Comment: Wish i could help but unfortunately i still don't understand the question.